# unix -https url download content and the same move another location

Tags: linux, shell, unix

i have URL https://my.waves.com/:r:/documents%20-/csv%20upload    that loaded the screen  then  show  edc_data.csv

above file edc_data.csv file move  unix Location(/equ/str/loaded)

can you please how to write shellscripts

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your URL https://my.waves.com/:r:/documents%20-/csv%20upload is correct and links to a CSV file, you can use this script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

curl -L 'https://my.waves.com/:r:/documents%20-/csv%20upload' > /equ/str/loaded/edc_data.csv

exit 0
```

This will download the file `edc_data.csv` and put it directly in `/equ/str/loaded/`.